# Usage of Enum<> generic type for variables

Tags: java, enums, findbugs

We have code somewhat similar to below, wherein we have enum and we check whether a given variable of that enum type is present in a list of that enum type.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    public static enum Color {RED, BLUE, GREEN};

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Enum<Color> red = Color.RED;

        List<Color> colorList = new ArrayList<>();
        colorList.add(Color.GREEN);

        // ** Find bugs reports warning - GC_UNRELATED_TYPES
        System.out.println(colorList.contains(red));
    }

}
```

Our QA team has run FindBugs against this code, and they have flagged a warning - GC_UNRELATED_TYPES, which states that

> GC: No relationship between generic parameter and method argument
>   ([GC_UNRELATED_TYPES](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html))
>
> This call to a generic collection method contains an argument with an
>   incompatible class from that of the collection's parameter (i.e., the
>   type of the argument is neither a supertype nor a subtype of the
>   corresponding generic type argument). Therefore, it is unlikely that
>   the collection contains any objects that are equal to the method
>   argument used here. Most likely, the wrong value is being passed to
>   the method.

My question is what is the use of variables whose types are `Enum<EnumClass>`, and should the FindBug warning be fixed.  We have currently planning to resolve it by using type casting.

```
 colorList.contains((Color) red)
```

Would that be correct way of fixing this warning if we assuming that we are not at liberty to change `Enum<Color>` to `Color` for variable `red`.

**Update:**
Reason we are not at liberty to change variables is - in real code, we have a GUI reusable control - `EnumListBox` - and it seems to be designed to work with any Enum - and hence, when we inherit from the `EnumListBox` to create specific uses - we have to override a method which accepts parameter of type, let says, `Enum<Color>`.

Comment: Change `colorList` to `List<Enum<Color>>`. Or just disable the warning here, because it's erroneous.

Comment: I'd question why it has to be `Enum<Color> red` and check whether it might maybe be possible to change that. Why aren't you at liberty to do that?

Comment: @AJNeufeld - Read the question. *we are not at liberty to change Enum<Color> to Color for variable red*

Comment: @BackSlash but AJNeufeld (and Thomas) are questioning *why* that is.

Comment: @AndyTurner Just Thomas. AJNeufeld is not questioning anything. He just  wrote *Change red to Color red = Color.RED*, and the OP already said he can't do that.

Comment: TLDR: "How do I fix a warning without fixing the warning?"

Comment: @Thomas In real code, this part of GUI reusable control - `EnumListBox` - and it seems to be designed to work with any Enum - and hence, we have not much choice but to work with `Enum<Color>` when we inherit from the `EnumListBox` to create specific uses.

Comment: Hmm, it seems like `EnumListBox` is some custom or 3rd party code but if I'd design it I'd use `EnumListBox<T extends Enum<T>>` and thus `EnumListBox<Color>` would be possible. If it isn't would you care to elaborate a bit, e.g. post some code snippet or a link to that class' javadoc/sources (e.g. on grepcode) if possible?

Comment: @Thomas Its our internal code, and its defined like `public class EnumListBox<T extends Enum<T>>` - and it has a method with signature `public void selecteItem(Enum<T> enumValue)` - when we override this method in derived class, we check the passed in param against a list of Enums as shown in example in the question.   I am not sure why method has that signature, at the outset it looks like one could have used `public void selectItem(T enumValue)` - do you think I should change that? Some methods use parameter of type `EnumSet<T> enumSet` and many others use `Enum<T>`.

Comment: I'd definitely check whether you could use `selectItem(T value)` instead. Depending on how that method is called that refactoring shouldn't require too many changes. However, if you or your management deem the refactoring not worth the effort I'd also consider a simpler approach (e.g. that cast) that while not clean might cut costs. It's up to you (and I'd prefer the cleaner approach if possible).

Comment: Thanks @Thomas for the inputs.

Answer (score 5):

`Enum` is like `Class`, it is not the entities of the `enum Color`, but the type of it, thus `Enum<Color>` is a similar construct to `Class<Color>`...

Your `Enum<Color> red = Color.RED;` line makes not much sense.
It should be `Color red = Color.RED;`...

Also see the comment below by **Joop Eggen**...

Comment: More explanation: `Enum<Color>` is the synthetic base class of `enum Color { ... }`. Hence the assignment worked. In contains, a _child_ class element of Color is required, not a parent class Enum which hypothetically is no Color.

Answer (score 1):

As you can read from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html), `Enum<?>` is the father of every enum.

The problem here is that FindBugs now only that:

- the list has elements of type `Color`
- You are trying to is of type `Enum`

This is definitely a case where FindBugs is issuing a warning on something which you know is not really dangerous, probably because it is not able to infer the relation between `Color` and `Enum<Color>` (the warning description clearly states that.)

The cleanest way is changing the type of `red`, but if you cannot, casting should be good enough. On the other hand, using `Enum<Color>` is more verbose and does not add clarity to the code, so I would investigate on the need to declare it that way.